# Did the early church believe in the Papacy?

Tags: history, bible

Roman Catholics believe that St. Peter was the first Pope, had primacy over the church and was given a pastoral role by the Lord Jesus Christ himself, we know the scripture argument for the papacy, which is Matthew 16:16-18:

> And Simon Peter answered and said, Thou art the Christ, the Son of the
> living God.
>
> And Jesus answered and said unto him, Blessed art thou, Simon Barjona:
> for flesh and blood hath not revealed it unto thee, but my Father
> which is in heaven.
>
> And I say also unto thee, That thou art Peter, and upon this rock I
> will build my church; and the gates of hell shall not prevail against
> it

but is there any historical evidence from AD 100-200 AD that the early church had a pope, who was the sole leader of the church of the one true church?